# The method list(String) in the type FtpClient is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, sun

I have this line of code in my project:

```
TelnetInputStream list = client.list();
```

where `client` is of type `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient`. Due to some changes in my development environment, I get an error in the above mentioned line of code:

> The method list(String) in the type FtpClient is not applicable for
>   the arguments ()

From what I read online, I realized that this line of code can be replaced with something like this:

```
InputStream list = client.list(path);
```

The old `list()` doesn't need parameters, while the new one needs some kind of path and I am completely lost in this.

Comment: `Parameters:
path a String containing the pathname of the directory to list or null for the current working directory.` Have you tried passing null ?

Comment: I tried it now and I got `Unhandled exception type FtpProtocolException`

Comment: You should also have to call `completePending() has to be called once the application is finished reading from the stream.`